# Taking the intersection of two timestamp range conditions in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['1998-03-01', '2001-04-01','1998-06-01','2001-08-01','2001-05-03'], 
    'node1': [1, 1, 2,2,3],
 'node2': [8,316,26,35,44],
 'weight': [1,1,1,1,1], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])
print(df)

mask1 = (df['date'] > '1998-01-01 00:00:01') & (df['date'] <= '2000-01-01 
00:00:01')
mask2 = (df['date'] > '2000-01-01 00:00:01') & (df['date'] <= '2003-01-01 
00:00:01')

mask = pd.concat((mask1, mask2), axis=1)
slct = mask.all(axis=1)
print df.ix[slct]
```

The above is my attempt.The dataset(the above is a toy dataset) has 4 columns that is node1,node2,weight,timestamp. I want to create two sets of rows with the condition :set1 should have rows whose timestamp is between the years 98-00 and set 2 the years 00-02.

Also both the sets  should rows which are in both the year ranges(98-00 and 00-02).

So in the above example the two sets should be {1,2} and {1,2}.3 should be excluded as it appears in the 00-02 range only.
But I am getting empty frame in the answer.
Firstly I did mask1 and mask2 to get rows satisfying the individual ranges and then I concat them to find intersection of the two conditions.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: In the above case the answer should be node: {1,1,2,2}.Only the node1:{3} should be excluded.

Comment: Why is 3 excluded the year is 2001 na?

Comment: because I need the nodes which have appeared in both 98-00 and 00-02. 3 is only in the range 00-02.

Comment: I understand the problem now do check my solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby with isin to know date contain both 1998-2000 and 2000-2002 i.e use mask based on groupby of node1 like this

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
mask = df.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin([1998,1999,2000])).any())
mask2 = df.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin([2000,2001,2002])).any())

df[df['node1'].isin(mask[mask & mask2].index)] # Get the dataframe
```

**Explanation** :

`mask` and `mask2` will give the mask like

```
mask                  mask2
(node1                  node1
 1     True           1    True
 2     True           2    True
 3    False           3    True
 dtype: bool,        dtype: bool)
```

Later we can use `&` to get the mask based on truth table, a new mask with only true values i.e

```
mask[mask & mask2]
```

```
node1
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

Select the df based on the new mask i.e

```
df['node1'].isin(mask[mask & mask2].index)
```

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: node1, dtype: bool
```

Output:

```
df[df['node1'].isin(mask[mask & mask2].index)]
```

```
        date  node1  node2  weight
0 1998-03-01      1      8       1
1 2001-04-01      1    316       1
2 1998-06-01      2     26       1
3 2001-08-01      2     35       1
```

Comment: I think I didnt  understand the "After using & will give the mask" step.Could you explain it? thanks

Comment: this error is showing :AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: I thought your date column is in standard datetime dtype. So you need to use `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer now and upvote when you get enough reputation. Have a good day

Comment: This step mask[mask & mask2]. Shouldnt this be mask[mask1 & mask2]? The & of the two mask (mask1 and mask2) should be stored in a new variable mask.

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar I used `mask` instead of mask1. You can use it as you like. Im not storing them in `mask` variable .

Comment: The intersection of the two mask should be stored in a new variable?

Comment: No need we can use any one of the mask to get the values. Im selecting only True values from mask variable. You can aslo do `mask2[mask&mask2]` . If you want you can store that mask in a new variable `new_mask` and pass it to `..isin(new_mask)`

Comment: Hey I am running this code on actual dataset and the problem I am having is that for the year range (98 -00) it is printing all the rows of the node which is in the condition.I just want those rows from the selected rows which have the date range.Could you please help me out?

Comment: If answer is accepted its better to open a new question. So other users might also help you out too.

Comment: There is a change in the output requirement.Should I edit this or ask a new question?Sorry I am new here.

Comment: A new question is much better.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems here. Firstly mask1 and mask2 only give you booleans. You need to index your dataframe using these 2 booleans.

Second, your pd.concat takes an iterable as an argument and you have provided objects.

Check this out

```
data = { 'node1': [1, 1, 2,2,3], 'node2': [8,316,26,35,44], 'weight': [1,1,1,1,1], 'date' : 
        ['1998-03-01', '2001-04-01','1998-06-01','2001-08-01','2001-05-03'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask1 = df.loc[(df['date'] > '1998-01-01 00:00:01') & (df['date'] <= '2000-01-01 00:00:01'), :]
mask2 = df.loc[(df['date'] > '2000-01-01 00:00:01') & (df['date'] <= '2003-01-01 00:00:01'), :]
pd.concat([mask1, mask2], axis = 0)
```

I am still not sure how exactly you want your output. Also I would recommend stop using .ix and start getting used to using .loc and .iloc

Comment: In the above case the answer should be node: {1,1,2,2}.Only the node1:{3} should be excluded as the node 3 is only appearing in the range 00-02 and not in 98-00.Others are appearing in both the year ranges 98-00 and 00-02.