# Displaying only the intersection of date range rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378603/taking-the-intersection-of-two-timestamp-range-conditions-in-pandas/46387549?noredirect=1#comment79955271_46387549)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['1998-03-01 00:00:01', '2001-04-01 00:00:01','1998-06-01 00:00:01','2001-08-01 00:00:01','2001-05-03 00:00:01','1994-03-01 00:00:01'], 
        'node1': [1, 1, 2,2,3,2],
     'node2': [8,316,26,35,44,56],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

mask = df.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin([1998,1999,2000])).any())
mask2 = df.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin([2001,2002,2003])).any())


print df[df['node1'].isin(mask[mask & mask2].index)]
```

The output I require are the nodes which are in the year range (98-00) and (01-03) but also it should only display the rows which are in both the ranges.

Expected Output-

```
node1          node2         date
1                8          1998-03-01
1               316         2001-04-01
2               26          1998-06-01
2              35           2001-08-01
```

right now this code is also printing this row: 2 56 1994-03-01 too.

Comment: Why is 2005 here in date?

Comment: I edited the output.It was a typing error

Comment: I didnt get you.

Comment: Because I need the date ranges which are in both (98-00) and (01-03).Since node 3 only appears in 2001-05-3 its excluded.

Comment: Chaitali check out my answer

Comment: thanks a lot.This helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to first remove the dates that are not in both the date ranges then apply mask i.e

```
l1 = [1998,1999,2000]
l2 = [2001,2002,2003]
ndf = df[df['date'].dt.year.isin(l1+l2)]
```

After getting the ndf:

**Option 1:** You can go for dual groupby mask based approach i.e

```
mask = ndf.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin(l1)).any())
mask2 = ndf.groupby('node1').apply(lambda x : (x['date'].dt.year.isin(l2)).any())

new =  ndf[ndf['node1'].isin(mask[mask & mask2].index)]
```

Thank you @Zero

**Option 2:** You can go for groupby transform

```
new = ndf[ndf.groupby('node1')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.dt.year.isin(l1).any() & x.dt.year.isin(l2).any())]
```

**Option 3:** groupby filter

```
new = ndf.groupby('node1').filter(lambda x: x['date'].dt.year.isin(l1).any() & x['date'].dt.year.isin(l2).any())
```

Output :

```
                 date  node1  node2  weight
0 1998-03-01 00:00:01      1      8       1
1 2001-04-01 00:00:01      1    316       1
2 1998-06-01 00:00:01      2     26       1
3 2001-08-01 00:00:01      2     35       1
```

Comment: Don't need two groupbys with `ndf[ndf.groupby('node1')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.dt.year.isin(l1).any() & x.dt.year.isin(l2).any()`

Comment: Or, use `filter` like `ndf.groupby('node1').filter(lambda x: x['date'].dt.year.isin(l1).any() & x['date'].dt.year.isin(l2).any())`